# Как работают шрифтовые иконки?

Tags: icon, шрифты, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте. Не разжуете процесс работы шрифтовых иконок?

Это такие, как в `bootstrap`, например. Чтобы можно было и размер, и цвет менять и анимацию применять, при этом ничего не расползется.

Я не понимаю, как они работают:

1. подключаются какие-то шрифты;
2. дальше тегу `i` в `:before` контент какой-то странный прописывается.

В общем, ничего не понятно, как это работает (вроде бы на svg, т.е. векторной графике, а в bootstrap png-спрайт с ними лежит).

Вот, например, хочу я свою шрифтовую иконку создать, что мне делать?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

Каждый шрифт имеет таблицу символов (те же буквы, цифры и подобное). Эти символы являются векторными объектами. Поэтому можно менять цвет и менять размер без потери качества. В иконических шрифтах таблица состоит из векторных иконок вместо тех же букв, например. Каждый символ в шрифте имеет свой код. Его можно в HTML писать. Но в том же бутстрапе, да и вообще во всех нормальных иконических шрифтах это сделано через CSS и свойства content, значением которого является код символа.

UPD. А попробовать можно вот [так](http://rafaltomal.com/how-to-create-and-use-your-own-icon-fonts/) или же загуглить "create icon font"

UPD2. А спрайт - это вроде фолбэк. Но не могу утверждать. Но там юзаются именно шрифты